# Strip html tags from ArcMap table

Tags: arcmap, kml, kmz

I am importing a KMZ we receive as output from an iOS app into ArcMap using the KML to layer tool.  The resulting table includes a "pop-up info" column that contians cells with marked up tags like:

`<table><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>Stakes for monitoring 2 stakes</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Time</td><td>N/A</td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>N/A</td></tr></table>`

Is there a simple way to strip these html tags with the field calculator and VB Script / Python within ArcMap, or from the KMZ itself somehow prior to importing?

Thanks!

would a period at the end of a sentence interrupt the script?  That's the only thing I noticed between the stopping point cells...

`<table><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>View northwest toward point between alignment and high bank. Standing on alignment on left (left) bank of stream channel.</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Time</td><td>N/A</td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Photos</td><td><img src="files/310.jpg"/><br/></td></tr></table>`

Comment: I'm not sure why it's stopping midway. It's working on my end if you use the first code block with your error text.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to extract `Stakes for monitoring 2 stakes` with the following code. I read over the official Python docs on the [xml module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

kmz = '''<table><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>Stakes for monitoring 2 stakes
</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Time</td><td>N/A</td></tr><tr>
<td valign="top">Description</td><td>N/A</td></tr></table>'''

extracted = fromstring(kmz)[0][1].text
```

You could use field calculator to perform this:

Parser:

```py
Python
```

Code Block:

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring
def parser(kmz):    
    try:
        return fromstring(kmz)[0][1].text
    except:
        return "Not Extracted!"
```

Expression:

```py
parser(!field_name!)
```

I tested it and it works (for your example at least).

Comment: Hi Paul - thanks, that seems to be what I'm after.  Could you point me in the right direction to be able to apply this to an entire column in a layer table?  I have a whole column filled with lines like the example and would like to convert all of it to a new field in the same table, if possible.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @Michael, assuming you can use calculate field on a table, my edited code should work.

Comment: Hi Paul - I get "a field name was not found or there were unbalanced quotation marks"

Comment: Actually i had that on VB, on Python I still get "Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 2)"

Comment: @Michael, you need to insert the field name that stores your data.

Comment: Hi Paul - so in your example both line 2 "def parser (xxx)", line 4, and later in the expression "parser(xxx)" are both my field name (xxx) exactly as it appears when I double click in the field calculator, correct? mine comes out to be "!PopupInfo!" for example with a space before and after between parentheses like "parser( !PopupInfo! )" - thanks for being patient!

Comment: @Michael, the only line to need to change is Expression. You'll run Calculate Field on a new field you add (name doesn't matter) and the expression will read `parser( !PopupInfo! )`. The spaces around the exclamation points are purely for readability.

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for all of your help, I've got it working now, although I have one table where it runs fine but stops halfway down the column of new clean text cells, returning a "ERROR 000539: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal (<expression>, line 1)" -- I can't find any significant difference between the last successful cell and the one where it stops, the remaining cells are null in the new cleanup up column...any thoughts?  Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Michael, could you edit your post to include the text that's not working?

Comment: Sure:   <table><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>Near MP 38 Overall slope about 17 to 18 degrees. Movement to the west, northwest. 2 scarps plus ground cracks.</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Time</td><td>Nov 8, 2011, 9:37</td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Photos</td><td>N/A</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Description</td><td>N/A</td></tr></table>

Comment: @Michael, it works for me in Python. I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: <table><tr><td valign="top">Description</td><td>View northwest toward point between alignment and high bank. Standing on alignment on left (left) bank of stream channel.</td></tr><tr bgcolor='3aafe8'><td valign="top">Time</td><td>N/A</td></tr><tr><td valign="top">Photos</td><td><img src="files/310.jpg"/><br/></td></tr></table>

Comment: oops, and in the above cell, gets halfway through the column and stops on the above

Comment: @Michael, please edit these into your post instead of putting them here.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a newline character in any of the rows being calculated, the Python parser on the Calculate Field tool will choke, producing the dreaded `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` error you came across, with no way of avoiding or even catching the error so you can at least skip that row and continue with the rest.

This is true all the way up to 10.1 SP1. I am not sure if they fixed it in 10.2.

See: [Removing return/newline (\n) character from Field using Python and Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/44460/753)

You'll have to either search for and fix these manually beforehand, or use an `UpdateCursor` within a Python script. You *may* also be able to use [VBScript and MSXML/XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9823181/386205) but I have not tried this and it just sounds icky so I won't :)

Comment: Ew. That's not cool at all.

Comment: Thanks guys, I like hearing that it's sort of a bug vs. me just having a typo, etc. I'll look into the workaround you mentioned.  Thanks for being patient Paul.