# Arcmap record value is not displaying entirely

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table

On this project i have a column composed of numeric and alphanumeric values. The data comes from multiple sources, so it is quite messy. Using python I am trying to filter the data and copy the values in new columns(were there are only numbers, copy the number in a new field; were there are only letters copy them to a new field, if alphanumeric split the numbers from the other characters etc.) I first filtered by "only numbers". I observed after running the script that a few "only numbers" were left behind. When I copied the value into Notepad a string appear after after the number. I stared editing and click-ed on that number, and sure enough the string appeared (only to vanish as i clicked somewhere else)
One co-worker suggested that some "n/" or a special command was used when entering that values. Simply copying the value to a new field wont reveal all. I am not allowed to alter the content of this column. What can i do to see all the content of that record?
[image: the record, with and without click]

Comment: Why don't you just type `101` or `101RADIAT` into that field and see if it overwrites the unwanted value?  I've not tested but your co-worker's theory about a `\n` sounds reasonable to me.  Without your question including a Python code snippet that shows how your field was populated it is hard to provide more advice than that.

Comment: I could, but I must not change the original field. I am supposed to break the information into multiple columns, leaving the first column unaltered. I did try to edit, and if overwritten the value remains as I type it(but i must overwrite all the value, else it will keep vanishing after the number value)

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were saying that the field values were written there via Python but I think you are saying that they are of unknown origin and first showed up when you tried to process them using Python.  It may be worth editing your question to try and make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44460/how-to-remove-return-newline-n-character-from-field-using-python-and-field-ca):

As [Jason](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/391/jason-scheirer) sugested, just replacing /n, /r using they char. value will do the trick. And it did.

```
!FieldName!.replace(chr(10), "").replace(chr(13), "")
```

In field calculator returned the full value.